# Pandas dataframe - sort by partial numeric count of years

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, bar-chart

I have got a pandas data frame with 26 columns. I need to create barplot based on unique values of a column in particular order. I have managed to extract unique values of the column in an array. Now I want to sort it out in particular order. Is there any way? 
**NOTE:**
I would prefer not to disturb the index of the dataframe, based on this column.

**my code**

```
  e= df['emp_length'].dropna().unique()
  e = np.sort(e)
  sns.countplot(x='emp_length',order=e,data=df)
```

**The array e is ordered as below**

```
    array(['1 year', '10+ years', '2 years', '3 years', '4 years', '5 years',
       '6 years', '7 years', '8 years', '9 years', '< 1 year'],
        dtype=object)
```

**However, I want the array to be ordered as below**

```
    array(['< 1 year','1 year', '2 years', '3 years', '4 years', '5 years',
       '6 years', '7 years', '8 years', '9 years', '10+ years'],
        dtype=object)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Close what need is use `natsorted`, but then is necessary change order - add last value to first:

```
a = np.array(['1 year', '10+ years', '2 years', '3 years', '4 years', '5 years',
       '6 years', '7 years', '8 years', '9 years', '< 1 year'])

from natsort import natsorted
b = natsorted(a)
print (b[-1:] + b[:-1])
['< 1 year', '1 year', '2 years', '3 years', 
 '4 years', '5 years', '6 years', '7 years', 
 '8 years', '9 years', '10+ years']
```